# git format-patch with a list file instead of numbered files

Tags: git

`git format-patch` normally generates patch files named like this:

```
0001-Something.patch
0002-Whatever.patch
```

Instead, I want to generate patch filenames with commit messages, but no numbers:

```
Something.patch
Whatever.patch
```

and a single file that lists all the patches in the correct order.

I will also need an equivalent `git am` to apply these patches.

Can `git` do this? And if not, how would you do it with scripts or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `Unix-like` systems you can do this to remove an initial number up to the first `-`:

```
$ git format-patch  120c547..2b05980  | while read x; do mv "$x" $(echo "$x" | cut -d '-' -f2-); done
```

You can easily apply such patches with `git am` as this commands takes both `mbox` and `Maildir` - just `cp` all patches into a directory and tell `git am` to look for patches in this directory.  For example:

```
$ git am /tmp/patches
```